# TypeScript: Convert Array to Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to write a generic type for a function which converts array to object as below:

```
type ObjType = { id: number; name: string; status: string };
const zzx: ObjType[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "A",
    status: "a"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "B",
    status: "b"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "C",
    status: "c"
  }
];

function arrayToObject<T>(
  arr: T[],
  key: string | number
): Record<string | number, T> {
  const result: Record<string, T> = {};
  for (const item of arr) {
    const value = item[key as keyof typeof T];
    result[value] = item;
  }
  return result;
}

const xx = arrayToObject<ObjType>(zzx, "id");
```

I have read somewhere that generic types could be passed as params in <> brackets.
But, I am not seeing the type (ObjType) in the function which I am passing from the function call.
And also getting below error in line `item[key as keyof typeof T];`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.
```

Can someone please tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing the Generic type parameter, it'd check your usage, not the Generic type implementation, i.e. the usage of a type doesn't matter at all in validating the type itself!

You may customize your Generic type a bit to get something that works fine,
And remember, there's no one correct solution, it always depends on your needs!

Check out [this possible solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCrmgXigbygSwCYBcUAdgK4C2cEATgNwkCG5ERAzsNTsQOb3sPBSrNhy7coAX1oAoAMYB7YuygAvFQA8i8ZKgDaAXSgZd0qFlNnchKAEYANBbPEmLKACIAgm4eWo-QcLuDG4WEj7mvvhEAEzhTi5EbgBC3o5+wAJCiXAhZmEWmGlRUADMcYzMiQDCqb7+We6yuZLS+jLSoJBQANIoXRjsnDxQAD4kFFTUHahQAOIQxDQCEHjaADxIAHxGUABKEArUeGu9qHZQW9LSAGakxLLAOIpQDNTUDCBI8toHwBtQEHUwAWeFYewO8iOJz6EHOdwA1sR5AB3YibTYACgsr2oRCQBnC8IgICIp0g0gAlER5ot3sDVogNttCmYFEpgFBqBBWKQADbAakLJb09ZbHaYKQWa6QqAYtnKHDA8hQeTXF5vCkRSzyjkANwYvNI6FwSt0RJAbTSXJ5-N0+sN0AYYLJEEMGEVEHIMjyFi5gmoxE53L5wBkEiuOqg6nUOxxHy+Pwea20MMxanU5zc+DcFNoQA)

first, for simplicity, I've added these types

```
type KType = string | number
type GeneratedObj<T> = Record<KType, T>
```

Note that you are returning `result` so it should be the same type of the function return type

for the function type, I've changed it to:

```
function arrayToObject<T extends Record<KType, unknown>>(
  arr: T[],
  key: KType
): GeneratedObj<T> {
...
...
```

You are expecting `T` to have a key that should be used in a place where you need to pass a `string` or a `number`, then you can just tell typescript that information, that this `T` extends this shape, an object that has a key of type `string | number`,
Regarding value, you can type it if you know its type, if it can be anything you can leave it as `unknown`

now you can directly do:

```
const value = item[key];
```

but because the value of `T` props is defined now as `unknown`
we need to cast the type of `value` in the next line:

```
result[value as KType] = item;
```